# Pipe Contents Into Grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a command which outputs groups I'm a member of as text:

```
$ groups
dbadmin hdpcl3 stargroup9 jorgesgroup ...
```

I would like to check if this output contains a group I have in mind. I tried:

```
$ groups > mygroups.txt
$ grep -R "stargroup9" mygroups.txt
stargroup9
```

This works, but I'd like to do it in one line without creating a temporary file. One way that would be neat, as it would generalize, would be to know how to:

```
$ groups | grep -R "stargroup9" .
```

Where '.' means put the input here, like in [R's dplyr/magrittr](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/articles/magrittr.html) syntax:

```
> my_species %>% filter(iris, Species == .)
```

Comment: Note: there's something fishy in your example. I mean `groups` prints groups in one line, so `grep -R anything mygroups.txt` should print either the entire line or nothing.

Answer (score 3):

To make `grep` process its stdin you should invoke it without file (or directory) names as operands. This is a straightforward, although not the best solution:

```
groups | grep "stargroup9"
```

This is way better:

```
groups | grep -E '(^| )stargroup9( |$)'
```

where `(^| )` matches the beginning of the line or a space character, `( | $)` matches a space character or the end of the line; so e.g. a group named `stargroup98765` is not a match.

`-E` uses extended regular expressions. As a basic regular expression (without `-E`) the pattern should look like this: `\(^\| \)stargroup9\( \|$\)` (and it should be single-quoted). I used `-E` because the pattern is more readable this way.

You may encounter an advice with a pattern like `\bstargroup9\b`, where `\b` anchors at word boundary (or `grep -w stargroup9` which is eqivalent). Do not use this approach here. The problem is group names can contain `-` but this character (as far as `\b` is concerned) separates words. In effect the pattern can match e.g. a group named `stargroup9-123foo`. If you are in this group but not in `stargroup9`, the pattern with `\b` will mislead you (and the same applies to `grep -w`).

In a script you may want to check if you're a member without printing any output from `grep`. Use `-q` to make the command quiet. Its exit status is enough. Examples:

```
groups | grep -qE '(^| )stargroup9( |$)' && do_something
if groups | grep -qE '(^| )stargroup9( |$)'; then …
```

---

What is wrong with your approach?

`grep -R` reads files under specified directories recursively. The option changes nothing if you specify only file(s) (i.e. non-directory).

If you want `grep` to read from its stdin (like in `groups | grep …`), you cannot specify any operands (files or directories). Then you cannot use `-R` because without operands the option makes `grep` process the current directory, not stdin.

Side note: `-R` is not specified by POSIX, therefore not portable.

---

I think `groups` may produce output in a form of

```
username : group1 group2 …
```

especially if you specify the user name (`groups username`). If so, you may want to remove everything excessive first. Since `:` cannot appear anywhere else (it's not a valid character in user/group name), the following command should work regardless of whether `groups` generates output starting with `username :` or not:

```
groups username | sed 's/.*: //' | grep -E '(^| )groupname( |$)'
```

Comment: Instead of the funky regex, try `grep -w groupname`

Comment: Oh right, my reading of this answer was clearly too cursory; sorry about that.